# Can free-format code be included in fixed-format code?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I inherited a fixed-format file FFTRUN.f
The beginning of that files looks like this:

```
  SUBROUTINE FFTRUN_2e 
  USE, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
  USE FFTWmod, ONLY : FFTWplan_fwd, FFTWplan_inv, FFTWplanReady
  INCLUDE 'INCL_PARAM.FOR'
  INCLUDE 'INCL_PRATT.FOR'
  INCLUDE 'INCL_XYZ.FOR'
  INCLUDE 'FFTW3.f03'

  PARAMETER (NDIM=2, NDAT=IMAX*JMAX)
  DIMENSION NN(NDIM),DATA(NDAT)
  COMPLEX*16 FACTR,SCATT(IMAX,JMAX),WAVINC,DATA

  IF (.not.FFTWplanReady) THEN
      FFTWplan_fwd = fftw_plan_dft_2d(nn2,nn1,data,data,
 &                FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE)
      FFTWplan_inv = fftw_plan_dft_2d(nn2,nn1,data,data,
 &                FFTW_BACKWARD,FFTW_MEASURE)
  ENDIF
```

I would compile it using

```
    gfortran -c FFTRUN.f
```

however, it fails because fftw3.f03 is free form. Is there a way I can accomplish this include without having to reformat the fftw3.f03 to fixed-format?

This is a massive piece of software, so it's not possible for me to reformat the entire rest of the project which is fixed format.

Comment: thanks...I'm curious to see if others have different suggestions, but if you post that as an answer I may eventually accept it.

Comment: Separate compilation and link is how I solve this problem.  An alternative would be to use one of the software tools to reformat the fixed-form source to free-form.  In my experience, they work well if the FORTRAN 77 code is standard compliant.  Otherwise manual fixups will be needed.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark is right - Free and fixed form cannot be mixed within the same translation unit (which is to say, file) so either translating one or compiling them separately is required.  INCLUDEing large swaths of code is weird and scary anyway.

Comment: note there is a "legacy fortran" version of fftw http://www.fftw.org/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You'll probably make quicker progress by compiling the two sources separately and linking them together. Since you're already using Fortran 90 features such as `use` this shouldn't cause you too much pain.

First, make sure that `fftw3.f03` contains a module which itself contains the function(s) you want to use. Delete the `include fftw3.f03` line and insert, with the other `use` statements, the statement `use fftw3_mod` (or whatever the module is called). Then modify your makefile to compile `fftw3.f03` before it compiles `fftrun.f`. That's about it.

Comment: Probably worth noting that this is processor specific.  Other compilers certainly allow for it, via in source compiler directives and the like.

Comment: I do not understand, my `fftw3.f03` in FFTW3 does not contain a module but just declarations. I always have to make a file with an empty module and include `fftw3.f03` there (with some other custom generic interfaces).

Comment: that's what i'm doing as well. Create a module that includes fftw3.f03, compile that with -free-form. Then compile the rest of my code with -std='legacy'. then link the two. I think it should work although I can't confirm yet...

Answer (score 0):

Source Code Useable for All Source Forms

To write source code that is useable for all source forms (free, fixed, or tab), follow these rules :

Blanks - Treat as significant (See Free Source Form ).

Statement labels - Place in column positions 1 through 5 (or before the first tab character).

Statements - Start in column position 7 (or after the first tab character).

Comment indicator - Use only! Place anywhere except in column position 6 (or immediately after the first tab character).

Continuation indicator - Use only &. Place in column position 73 of the initial line and each continuation line, and in column 6 of each continuation line (no tab character can precede the ampersand in column 6).

FROM : 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/510921

Comment: *Source Code Useable for All Source Forms* -- and achieve the worst of both worlds !  Further, readers take note, the tab character is not in the Fortran character set.  It is understood and accepted by almost all compilers but it is not standard.  The Intel page referred to makes it clear that `tab` form is non-standard.

Comment: This would lead to what the OP specifically tries to avoid -  the source code conversion.

Comment: in fairness he said he didn't want to convert the entire project. Converting FFTW3.f03 to fixed form may be worth a look.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't mess with the style of FFTW3.f03 because when this is deployed, the user's version will be free form.

Answer (score -1):

gfortran has an option `-ffree-form`. Look [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranGettingStarted)

Two suggestions:

1. Compile first only fftw3.f03 with `-ffree-form` option. Then compile the whole project as you usually do, but with with resulted object file `fftw3.o` .
2. Compile the whole project with `-ffree-form` option.